# Is there a better way to randomly choose from a list than this:

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
choices = [a,a,a,a,b,b,c]
random.choice(choices)
```

As you can see a is most likely to be chosen but is there a better/shorter way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean choosing from `[a,b,c]`, but not uniformly?

Comment: What's wrong with this way? What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Idk say i want to print a random choice but there is more chance of getting a than b or c

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga its very long if there are loads of choices. By better i mean less code to do the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `choices`, not `choice`, you can specify a weight for each element.

```
random.choices([a,b,c], [4,2,1])
```

The second argument are the relative weights for each element in the first argument. For example, in the following you can see that `a` was chosen roughly twice as often as `b` and roughly four times as often as `c`.

```
>>> import collections, random
>>> collections.Counter(random.choices('abc', [4,2,1], k=100))
Counter({'a': 58, 'b': 25, 'c': 17})
```

Comment: How is this more random if you're defining the weights?

Comment: `random.choice('abc')` would have a 1/3 chance of returning `a`, `b`, or `c`. `random.choices('abc', [4,2,1])` will choose `a` 4 out of 7 times, `b` 2 out of 7 times, and `c` 1 out of 7 times. It's still random, but it's not a uniform distribution.

Comment: @darshvader because one is more likely to be chosen

Comment: @chepner ahhhh ok, very nice explanation. For some reason I was forgetting that even randomly, they'll still align uniformly.

Comment: @chepner which has the same function as the way I originally did it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Python 3.6+ (support for weights in `random.choices`), you can construct a population:

```
import random
a, b, c = 'abc'

weighted = [(a, 4), (b, 2), (c, 1)]

population = [x for x, weight in weighted for _ in range(weight)]
random.choice(population)
```

If you are worried about performance for large weight values, you can use `itertools.accumulate` and `bisect`:

```
import bisect
import itertools
import random

choices = ['a', 'b', 'c']
weights = [4, 2, 1]
cumulative_weights = list(itertools.accumulate(weights))

print(choices[bisect.bisect(cumulative_weights, random.random() * cumulative_weights[-1])])
```

Comment: This is literally same as OP is using.

Comment: @Austin The point is to avoid typing `a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a`... for large values.

Comment: @Tomothy32 exactly, thank you. I thought that was obvious

Comment: This will be highly inefficient if the weights are very large.

Comment: @ekhumoro I added a more general approach, though it heavily complicates things.